# How to add link to "Linked Data" in researchgate for a published paper?

Tags: publications

It seemed to have been possible to add a tab called "Linked data" to the profile page of a paper published in a journal in researchgate. This data is essentially a zipped file containing problem instances or code that I would like share.

See a snapshot of one such instance from my profile from some time ago:

[image]

However, I seem to have either forgotten how to do that or else that provision has been removed from researchgate. I have been trying to add such a tab titled "Linked data" to a recent paper of mine but the option does not seem to be available. Please see below:

[image]

Online google search and email to researchgate support have not yielded any result.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, since I have not used it, but in that page, there is a dropdown menu beside the "Save" above, that has an option "Add supplementary resources". Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @GoodDeeds I have tried that. Unfortunately, that path explicitly disallows addition of a zipped file. Earlier, in the first snapshot I linked to, the linked data led to a page where people could download the zipped file.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Indeed your answer turned out to be correct. I think the system in researchgate is setup to disallow addition of such files to preprints but allows such addition only to final published version. Thanks!

Comment: Great, I think you should make that an answer.